# Alternate row color in gridview

Tags: gridview

i am using a gird view and fetching from datatase and populating the gridview for applying alternate color in row i am using  AlternatingRowStyle

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server" > 
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#dcecf4"   />
</asp:GridView>
```

the above code gives alternate color in 2,4,6 etc., rows,but my requirement is the rows alternate color should start from 1,3,5 etc., rows

Answer (score 2):

You want `RowStyle` instead of `AlternatingRowStyle`:

```
<asp:GridView ... >
  <RowStyle CssClass="oddRow" />
  <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="evenRow" />
</asp:GridView ... >
```

Here I'm using styles, but you could specify something like `BackColor` directly.  As the style names indicate, `RowStyle` applies to the odd rows (1, 3, 5, ...) and `AlternatingRowStyle` applies to the even rows (2, 4, 6, ...).